# Acces an element in a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

This is probably very simple but I can't find it:

I want to acces an element in a vector of pointers

```
 class Tile
  {
  public:
    Tile(int xPosition, int yPosition, float tileWeight);
    float getValue() const {return value;};
    void setValue(float newValue) {value = newValue;};
    int getXPos() const {return xPos;};
    int getYPos() const {return yPos;};
    void setXPos(int newPos) {xPos = newPos;};
    void setYPos(int newPos) {yPos = newPos;}

  private:
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
    float value;
  };

class Enemy : public Tile
  {
  public:
    Enemy(int xPosition, int yPosition, float strength);
  };
```

In another class

```
std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;
enemies = myWorld->getEnemies(5);
```

How can I acces the value of just the first member in another class
I can't seem to acces it in another class

```
MySquare::movePlayer(std::vector <int> directions, std::vector<Enemy*> enemies,std::vector<int*> healthPks){

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example to call `getValue` function on the first item in the vector, use

```
enemies[0]->getValue();
```